# Paypal Authorization & Capture API For Android

Tags: android, paypal

I want to use the Paypal Authorization & Capture API inside Android.
I have found [a way to integrate it in a website](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_admin_authcapture), but is there any way to integrate the same thing in an Android app?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index

Here you can find sdk and example for android and others